# how to compile Leptonica library for windows x64 bit using VS2010?

Tags: c++, .net, windows

I can build Leptonica libraries(DLL) for 32-bit windows using VS2010 by the help  of http://www.leptonica.com/vs2008doc/building-liblept.html .
But when I change the Target into x64, I got below errors. How can I resolve this? Is it possible to compile the 32-bit source files in 64 bit?

*2>tiffio.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented referenced in function pixReadFromTiffStream
2>tiffio.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFReadScanline referenced in function pixReadFromTiffStream
2>tiffio.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFScanlineSize referenced in function pixReadFromTiffStream
2>tiffio.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFGetField referenced in function pixReadFromTiffStream*

Comment: ***How can I resolve this?*** Make sure all of the dependent libraries / dlls are x64. You can not use 32 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the x64 libraries or you have not correctly placed the x64 libraries where the linker is looking for them.

Comment: Yes, I only have the 32-bit libraries. Is there a way to build in 64 bit ?

Comment: Unfortunately, without the 64 bit libraries there is no way to build a 64 bit version of a native Windows binary.  The good news is that you can run a 32 bit process on a 64 bit machine so you should be able to get by with just having the 32 bit library.  Is there a specific requirement that requires a 64 bit dll?

Comment: yes, The client application needs a 64 bit version only which throws a BadImageFormatException if we use the 32 bit library.

Comment: Unless you can get source to build the library or get them to give you a 64 bit library your options are really limited.  One work around, albeit, not a very elegant one would be to wrap the library in a COM object that is hosted in an out of proc COM server.  This would allow the client application to be 64 bit and it would launch the 32 bit COM Server.  Performance would take a minor hit, but at least you would have everything working.